# Is there something known as Array type mismatch exception in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

My teacher has asked me to write a program in C# to handle "Array type mismatch exception". But i couldn't find anything in the net related to that. I just want to confirm if there exists something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ArrayTypeMismatchException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 3):

Let’s say Class2 derives from Class1, because C# language is covariant when it comes to assigning arrays following assignment is perfectly valid

```
Class1[] generalizedArray;
Class2[] specializedArray = new Class2[]{new Class2(),new Class2()};

generalizedArray= specializedArray;
```

But half way through if you assign an element like this

```
generalizedArray[0]=new Class1()
```

Compiler won`t even issue a warning. You will get a nasty **ArrayTypeMismatchException** at runtime instead. This is because you can’t have
two types of objects in an array like above

Read more about Covariance, contravariance and invariance in C# language in 
http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2008/12/30/covariance-contravariance-and-invariance-in-c-language.aspx

Comment: It's too bad that .net didn't include more families of array variable types including immutable, readable, and readable-and-permutable (all of which could safely be covariant, with the latter allowing elements to be swapped within an array but not allowing new elements to be stored in it).  I don't think I've seen any collection interfaces of the latter type, but such a design would allow sorting in statically-type-safe fashion.

Answer (score 1):

As cited in [`ArrayTypeMismatchException Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception.aspx) on MSDN:

> ArrayTypeMismatchException is thrown when the system cannot convert the element to the type declared for the array. For example, an element of type String cannot be stored in an Int32  array because conversion between these types is not supported. It is generally unnecessary for applications to throw this exception.

Use above link for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an exception class:

[Mismatch match exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arraytypemismatchexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It can happen at the *run-time* evaluation of argument lists.
Section 7.5.1.2 C# 5.0 mentions:

> •  For a reference or output parameter, the variable reference is evaluated and the resulting storage location becomes the storage location represented by the parameter in the function member invocation. If the variable reference given as a *reference* or *output* parameter is an array element of a reference-type, a run-time check is performed to ensure that the element type of the *array* is *identical* to the type of the parameter. If this check fails, a **System.ArrayTypeMismatchException** is thrown.

One simple example given in the spec for it:

```
class Test
{
    static void F(ref object x) {...}
    static void Main() {
        object[] a = new object[10];
        object[] b = new string[10];  //Array covariance
        F(ref a[0]);        // Ok
        F(ref b[1]);        // ArrayTypeMismatchException because the actual element type of b is string and not object.
    }
}
```