# JwtBearerOptions ArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt

I am using `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer version 1.0.0-rc1-final`

This line:

```
JwtBearerOptions bearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions( );
```

Gets `ArrayTypeMismatchException`, here is the stack trace. Any clues?

Here is the stack trace:

> Application startup exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a
>   type incompatible with the array.    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerOptions..ctor()
>   at ActiveCypherUserAuthAPI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in
>   D:\home\site\approot\src\ActiveCypherUserKeyAPI\Startup.cs:line 126
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object
>   instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[7]

EDIT:

The exception is thrown by the JwtBearerOptions class constructor. The single line of code shown above is all that is needed to reproduce the error when using version 1.0.0-rc1-final of Microsoft.ApsNet.Authentication. Something in the constructor is failing. My question is NOT "what is an ArrayType mismatch". My question is why is the constructor failing and is there a workaround.

Comment: Adding some code may be more helpful to find the issue you're running into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there something known as Array type mismatch exception in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477675/is-there-something-known-as-array-type-mismatch-exception-in-c)

Comment: @confusedandamused The exception is thrown by the JwtBearerOptions class constructor. The single line of code shown above is all that is needed to reproduce the error when using version 1.0.0-rc1-final of Microsoft.ApsNet.Authentication.  Something in the constructor is failing. My question is NOT "what is an ArrayType mismatch". My question is why is the constructor failing and is there a workaround.