# Casting from string array to object array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

In [this C# lesson from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/implement-exception-handling-c-sharp/3-examine-compiler-generated-exceptions), they discuss various types of exceptions. When discussing `ArrayTypeMismatchException`, they provide the following example:

```
string[] names = { "Dog", "Cat", "Fish" };
Object[] objs = (Object[])names;

Object obj = (Object)13;
objs[2] = obj; // ArrayTypeMismatchException occurs
```

The preceding text says that this is an examples where an attempt is being made to “store a numeric value in a string array”.

But how can that be the case? The array `objs` is an *object* array, having been cast to the class `Object[]`. It should not be a *string* array, right? So why can’t I add the *object* `(Object)13` to it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477675/is-there-something-known-as-array-type-mismatch-exception-in-c

Comment: *"It should not be a string array, right?"* [Yes it is](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZdBR3f)

Comment: @Cid Yes, I trust you, but *why*? Didn’t we just cast it to `Object[]`?

Comment: The same reason why you can have `Base a = new Derived();` but cannot have `Derived a = new Base();`. In that case, `Object[] objs = (Object[])names;` is still a **reference** to `names`, which is still a `string[]`

Comment: Do note that when you do: `objs[2] = obj.ToString()`, that after this the value of `names[2]` is also "13".

Comment: You can however do something like `Object[] objs2 = objs.ToArray(); Object obj = (Object)13; objs2[2] = obj;`

Comment: @Cid So casting a reference type doesn’t actually create a new copy of the (casted) object, but just references the same one? But potentially with access to less structure from it?

Comment: @Gaussler exactly